# Difference between standard I/O and lower-level I/O

Tags: c, io

I have two segments of code.

```
#define BUFFSIZE 30
#define STDIN_FILENO  0
#define STDOUT_FILENO 1
#define STDERR_FILENO 2
#include <strings.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    while ( (n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE)) > 0)
       if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n) != n)
        err_sys("write error");

    if (n < 0)
       err_sys("read error");

    exit(0);
}
```

And another

```
 #define STDIN_FILENO  0
 #define STDOUT_FILENO 1
 #define STDERR_FILENO 2
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <strings.h> 
 int main(void) {
    int c;
    while ( (c = getc(stdin)) != EOF)
       if (putc(c, stdout) == EOF)
            err_sys("output error");

    if (ferror(stdin))
        err_sys("input error");

    exit(0); }
```

For the first programme, I thought if I input a string whose length is larger than BUFFZISE, the characters whose indexes are larger than BUFFZISE will be eliminated. But it turned out not to be so. Why does this happen? And what is the major difference between these two I/O mechanism? Many thanks.

Comment: "For the first programme" - what's the difference? both have a loop. you have to explain what causes the misunderstanding. tell us what you think that code does. (my guess: you think it's reading lines)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the basic difference between I/O levels is that lower level is not buffered (in standard library).

In your case, the first example is reading and writing using your own buffer of size BUFFSIZE. In the second example, you are reading/writing by a single character relying on the fact that the buffering is done by the library. Otherwise, both examples are doing the same thing.

Lower level functions allow to use a few more options than higher level functions like non-blocking I/O. Also programs using higher level functions may be a bit slower. In your second example the data is copied (byte after byte) from an input buffer to an output buffer which does not happen in the first example.

BTW, your first example can miss some characters, the loop shall be something like:

```
while ( (n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE)) > 0) {
   int i, k = 0;
   do {
      i = write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf+k, n-k);
      if (i < 0) {err_sys("write error"); break;}
      k += i;
   } while (k < n);
}
```